# .bat file does not reload explorer.exe (win10)

Tags: batch-file, explorer

I've had no luck researching what I assume is a very simple issue - there are suggestions here via search but they did not resolve it for me

Advanced apologies if I have missed what has been faq'd/posted elsewhere - must state that beyond insanely simple code, mostly copied and pasted in, I've never written .bat files before

I'm writing a small .bat for sccm to run:

- An uninstall
- A clean up tool
- An install.msi
- A patch (msi)

Making my way through it, I got to step two, running the cleanup tool successfully after the uninstall - so getting rid of the old program with my .bat works 100% fine.

The issue with the uninstall and the cleanup tool is when run silently they do not prompt options - one of which states the program needs to kill explorer.exe

Ignoring potential solutions to prevent it closing explorer.exe;
I thought oh well no big deal, a cmd command "explorer.exe" boots explorer back up fine, I'll just throw that in my batch file

```
msiexec /x {APPID HERE} /qn /norestart
"%~dp0Remover.exe" /qn /norestart
explorer.exe
```

But it doesn't work - the uninstall/cleanup runs and I (and therefore any user) will be sat there with a blank "explorer-less" screen.

So I thoght ok I'll be specific

```
msiexec /x {APPID HERE} /qn /norestart
"%~dp0Remover.exe" /qn /norestart
**%windir%\**explorer.exe
```

Nope, same issue

I checked task manager and there seemed to still be an explorer task despite the blank screen - ok maybe I need to use more of an explorer restart than just launch it

```
msiexec /x {APPID HERE} /qn /norestart
"%~dp0Remover.exe" /qn /norestart
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
%windir%\explorer.exe
```

No dice

I've tried throwing in sleep in there to give it a sec after uninstalling the apps (no idea if this would help - didn't solve it anyway)
I've tried adding "Start" (Start %windir%\explorer.exe) - tna

I'm guessing you guys are going to say something like "dude, hit tab before line 3" or something painfully simple like that but... I've not managed to find the solution through a fair few google clicks and forum searches.

I've killed explorer manually and ran a batch file that just contains %windir%\explorer.exe and it makes explorer spring back to life... so why doesn't it action the same command after completing the two lines above it?

Thanks a lot

*edit*
Cheers tripehound

so this would read

```
start /wait msiexec /x {appID} /qn /norestart
start /wait "" "%~dp0Cleaner.exe" /qn /norestart
start /wait msiexec /i "%~dp0MSI.msi" /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress
start /wait msiexec /i "%~dp0MSI2.msi" /q REBOOT=ReallySuppress
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
%windir%\explorer.exe
```

Right? - the double quotes only for the cleaner as it is a .exe? Although the MSI presumably have the gui

Comment: Because MSIEXEC (and possibly the remover.exe) are GUI programs, they don't (normally) stop execution of the batch file while they run -- you are probably (re)starting explorer _before_ the uninstaller/remover kills the original one off.  Try changing the first line to `start /wait msiexec...` and the second to `start /wait "" "%~dp0Remover.exe"...` These should allow the first two lines to run to completion before restarting explorer.   (The empty `""` is needed in the 2nd line because if `start` sees a parameter in double-quotes, it uses it as the window's title).

Comment: Yes, your last edit is my suggestion. The extra double quotes are needed because if the first parameter to the `start` command has them, it is used as the title of the command window it opens instead of the command to run. The empty double quotes are used as the title so the rest of the line is correctly interpreted as the command to run.

Comment: It did not work :( Same issue - I'll try run it with the explorer.exe kill too.

taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
%windir%\explorer.exe

Comment: Nor did it work with the kill command

Comment: I figured it out - and it was because I was being stupid still! - the issue is, under an elevated cmd prompt it was trying to get my(/the) admin account to launch explorer.exe NOT my logged in account

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Tripehound - I'm sure I needed the addition of start /wait anyway but it turns out my issue was due to the fact I was running CMD "as" my admin account (we log in with base accounts and use our admin credentials to elevate)

So my cmd was essentially running the start /explorer under my admin account and I therefore didn't get explorer.exe back on my logged in base account

Now to go down the whole other path of.. how do I get the batch file (or call another file) which would run explorer as the current user *sigh*